# Django comment saving to DB but not to post

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

Comments are saving to DB but not linking to Post, unless I manually go to Admin page and link.

**MODELS.PY**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    info = models.TextField(max_length=2000)
    slug = models.SlugField(null=True, unique=True, max_length=300)
    created = models.DateField(null=True, auto_now_add=True)
    approved = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True)
    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True, primary_key=True, editable=False)


class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name="comments", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name="Name")
    comment = models.TextField(max_length=500, verbose_name="Comment")
    created = models.DateField(null=True, auto_now_add=True)
    approved = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True)
    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True, primary_key=True, editable=False)
```

**FORMS.PY**

```
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ['name','comment']
```

**VIEWS.PY**

```
def create_comment(request, slug):
    form = CommentForm()
    post = Post.objects.get(slug=slug)

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        comment = form.save()
        comment.post = post
        comment.save()

        messages.success(request, 'Your comment was successfully submitted!')
        return render(request, 'post.html', {'post': post, 'form':form})
    return render(request, 'post.html', {'post': post, 'form':form})
```

---

From Admin page I can add comment and manually link to post, but from frontend form, comment is created and saved to DB but not linked to any post. Any idea what I'm doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where does this `review` object instance come from, woudn't it be the `comment` object?

Also, check if the the form is valid:

```
def create_comment(request, slug):
    form = CommentForm()
    post = Post.objects.get(slug=slug)

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save()
            comment.post = post
            comment.save()

            messages.success(request, 'Your comment was successfully submitted!')
            return render(request, 'post.html', {'post': post, 'form':form})
            
    return render(request, 'post.html', {'post': post, 'form':form})
```

Comment: corrected review object instance and checked if form is valid but still not attaching comment to post, just saving as Null. Tried removing Null=True from model but then gives me an error since there is nothing to save it to

Comment: That is awkward, I have tested using your models and form as it is. Just changed the view, and it is saving the full object. Could you share your URL path to this view?

Comment: Your correction worked, I just had to delete and reset the DB because was getting an "operational error; column does not exist".

Checking if form is valid solved it. Thank you, much appreciated :)